# How do I remove all non alphanumeric word from a List<string>

Tags: c#, regex

How do I remove all non alphanumeric words from a list of strings (`List<string>`) ?

I found this regex `!word.match(/^[[:alpha:]]+$/)` but in C# how can I obtain a new list that contains only the strings that are purely alphanumeric ?

Comment: if c# then with linq `list.Where(x => Regex.IsMatch(x, @"^[a-zA-Z0-9]$")).ToList();`

Comment: You want to remove all the non-alphanumeric *characters* from all the strings? Or you want a new list that contains *only the strings that are purely alphanumeric*?

Comment: I want a new list that contains only the strings that are purely alphanumeric

Comment: A new list is not quite the same, as removing all the unwanted elements from an existing list.

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary shouldn't it be `list.Where(x => Regex.IsMatch(x, @"[a-zA-Z0-9]*")).ToList();` ?

Comment: @Thomas oh true. i forgot. pattern should be `^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use LINQ for this. Assuming you have a `theList` (or array or whatever) with your strings:

```
var theNewList = theList.Where(item => item.All(ch => char.IsLetterOrDigit(ch)));
```

Add a `.ToList()` or `.ToArray()` at the end if desired. This works because the `String` class implements `IEnumerable<char>`.

Comment: Actually, `[[:alpha:]]` class only matches letters, thus `Char.IsLetter()` must be used. However, it might be OP regex issue :)

Comment: OP says Alphanumeric. So `Char.IsLetterOrDigit` is correct

Comment: The OP needs *alphanumeric* strings, I assume that this includes numbers. The regex in the question is only an example that (s)he found elsewhere.

Answer (score 3):

```
  Regex rgx = new Regex("^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$");
  List<string> list = new List<string>() { "aa", "a", "kzozd__" ,"4edz45","5546","4545asas"};
  List<string> list1 = new List<string>();
  foreach (var item in list)
  {
     if (rgx.Match(item).Success)
     list1.Add(item);
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

With LINQ + regex, you can use this:

```
list = list.Where(s => Regex.IsMatch(s, "^[\\p{L}0-9]*$")).ToList();
```

`^[\\p{L}0-9]*$` can recognise Unicode alphanumeric characters. If you want to use ASCII only, `^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$` will work just as well.

Answer (score 0):

There's a static helper function that removes all non-alphanumeric strings from a List:

```
    public static List<string> RemoveAllNonAlphanumeric(List<string> Input)
    {
        var TempList = new List<string>();
        foreach (var CurrentString in Input)
        {
            if (Regex.IsMatch(CurrentString, "^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$"))
            {
                TempList.Add(CurrentString);
            }
        }
        return TempList;
    }
```

Comment: Your code will return all the string that contains at least one alphanumeric char